# Helpful flag dropoff after gaining voting rights

Tags: support, flags, vote-to-close, helpful-flags

After getting voting rights my helpful flag count seems to have not increased. I have 112 helpful flags, but none for about 8 months. This seems to be a side effect of gaining voting rights, since I no longer have to flag to close.

Is this dropoff in helpful flags simply an inevitable consequence of gaining voting rights, or is there something more I should be doing to be helpful?

On a side note, I noticed that if I do flag, it gets converted to a vote. What about obscure zombie posts that should be closed, but are not visited enough to get the five votes. How do I bring those to a moderator's attention so they get closed?

Comment: In what way is this a problem.  Why do you think that having a high helpful flag count is in any way important.  Fixing a bunch of posts yourself is *way* more helpful than telling mods to fix a bunch of stuff for you.

Comment: I am simply asking if the dropoff in helpful flags, means I am missing something, and not doing something I should to be more helpful.

Comment: "How do I bring those to a moderator's attention so they get closed?"  You don't.  That's what the close queue is for.  It is not the moderator's job to handle posts that the community is capable of handling on their own.

Comment: Do you think that voting to close is less helpful than flagging to close?

Comment: According to your [Flagged Posts page](http://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/1655700), you haven't flagged a post since Jun 24 '13.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Flagging for closure, when you have 3k+ rep, is silently converted to a vote to close, despite using the flag menu.

Comment: @Servy: Yeah, just figured that out.

Answer (score 2):

When users gain the ability to vote to close, they're expected to use their close votes for closing, rather than flagging for moderator attention.  This allows new users to give "supervised" input on closing questions, and when those users earn enough rep, they earn the privilege to vote to close without involving a moderator.

When you earn enough rep to get the Vote to Close privilege, your close flags are silently converted to a Vote to Close, so you no longer get "credit" for flagging in this way.

> What about obscure zombie posts that should be closed, but are not visited enough to get the five votes. How do I bring those to a moderator's attention so they get closed?

Cast a custom moderator flag.  In the custom description, say that *"This is an obscure zombie post that should be closed, but it's not being visited enough to get the five votes it needs to close."*

Comment: Yep, I understand all this, I just want to make sure my "helpful" count does not indicate there is something additionally I should be doing, but am not.

Comment: The helpful count does not increment for Recommend Closure flags, once you earn the VTC privilege.  The flag doesn't even register as a moderator flag, actually, since it never makes it into the mod queue.

Comment: @TylerDurden - There are plenty of things you can flag for, even after having the ability to vote to close, like spam, trolling, people asking questions in answers, etc. You don't have to feel compelled to do so, though. Many of our best users never flag anything, they just ask and answer questions.

Comment: @Brad Larson Thanks, that makes sense, I think I am not paying attention to spam and trolling, etc, ignoring it, when I should be flagging it. Thanks for suggesting that.